# pandas - Can't merge df/series and groupby then count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TL;DR:**
Have 2 dataframes with different sizes, but one 'id' column(in both df) that supposed to act as index. Need to merge them, group by 'sector' and 'gender' and count/sum entrys in each group.

**Long version:**

I have a dataframe with 'id', 'sector', among other columns, from company personnel. Another dataframe with 'id' and 'gender'. Examples bellow:

df1:

```
row*  id     sector           other columns
1     0      Operational           ...
2     0      Administrative        ...
3     1      Sales                 ...
4     2      IT                    ...
5     3      Operational           ...
6     3      IT                    ...
7     4      Sales                 ...
      [...]
150   100    Operational           ...
151   100    Sales                 ...
152   101    IT                    ...
```

***I don't really have a 'row' column, it's there just to make it easier to understand my problem.**

df2:

```
row*      id     gender
1         0      Male
2         1      Female
3         2      Female
4         3      Male
5         4      Male
          [...]
101       100    Male
102       101    Female
```

As you can see, one person can be in more then one sector (which seems to make my problem more complicated.)
I need to merge them together and then make a sum from how many male and female in each sector.

**FIRST PROBLEM**

Decided to make a new df to get only the columns 'id' and 'sector'.

```
df3 = df1[['id','sector']]
df3 = df3.merge(df2)
```

I get:

> No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None,
>   right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Tried using `.join()` instead of `.merge()` and I get:

> ['id'] not in index"

Tried now with `reset_index()` - Found in some of the answers around here, but didn't really solved my issue.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index() 
df3 = df1[['id','sector']] 
df3 = df3.join(df2)
```

What I got was this:

```
row*  id     sector                gender
1     0      Operational           Male
2     0      Administrative        Female
3     1      Sales                 Female
4     2      IT                    Male
5     3      Operational           Male
6     3      IT                    ...
7     4      Sales                 ...
          [...]
150   100    Operational           NaN
151   100    Sales                 NaN
152   101    IT                    NaN
```

It didn't respected the 'id' and just concatenated the column to the side. Since df2 only had 102 rows, I got `NaN` in the other rows(103 to 152), aside from the fact that the 'gender' was no longer accurate.

**SECOND PROBLEM**

Decided to power through that in order to get the rest of the work done. I tried this:

```
df3 = df3.groupby('sector','gender').size()
```

It raises:

> No axis named gender for object type < class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

What doesn't really make sense to me, because I can call `df3.gender` and I get the (entire) expected series. If I remove 'gender' from the line above, it actually group but just that doesn't work for me. Also tried passing the columns names befor groupby, to no avail.

**Expected result** should be something like this:

```
sector          gender   sum
operational     male     20
operational     female   5
administrative  male     10
administrative  female   17
sales           male     12
sales           female   13
IT              male     1
IT              female   11
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your first problem. I executed `df1[['id','sector']].merge(df2)` and got the expected answer. In the second problem, you forgot to pass a list to `groupby`: `df3.groupby(['sector','gender']).size()`.

Comment: Tried the `df3 = df1[['id','sector']].merge(df2)` but got the same error. No idea what could be wrong. Did you tried with df with diffrent lenghts? It seems that  pandas doesn't reconize my 'id' column as a 'common column' (assuming that's because of the lenght). Oh and the 2nd issue is solved. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can answer to my own question but I think I should since the issue is resolved.
The solutions were very simple, even though I don't understand some of the issues I got.

First problem added `on='id'` in the merge

```
df3 = df1[['id','sector']].merge(df2, on='id')
```

Second problem just missing a list, as pointed by @DYZ

```
df3.groupby(['sector','gender']).size()
```

Feeling quite stupid right now... Must be tired. Thanks DYZ and sorry for the trouble.